# Was Riemann really the first person to define definite integrals?

Tags: math-history, riemann-integration

So I am doing a study on Riemann, and one of his big things is apparently the "Riemann integral".

My understanding is that this concept was meerly the first definition of a definite integral, and because of this definition it was possible to calculate things like displacement thus allowing physics to calculate displacement of a particle moving along a line with a specefic velocity. Is this accurate? Was this all his definition was? Was he really the first?

I just find it kinda odd that something that one would think was discovered when the integral was first defined actually came quite a bit later.

Comment: One might argue that Riemann integration is not fundamentally different from the [method of exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion)

Comment: see also [wiki/Leibniz–Newton_calculus_controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy)

Comment: In asking for some historical perspective, it would be helpful for you to state your level of study.

Comment: Sophomore college

Comment: @Hagen: I agree, integrals are fundamentally exhausting. (Actually,forget the "funda" there!) :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton and Leibniz separately developed the theory of integration and implicitly the notion of a definite integral, this was much earlier than Riemann, Riemann made the concept of integration more rigorous, including the concept of the definite integral.